# php curl CURLOPT_PASSWDFUNCTION option

Tags: php, security, curl

I can't use php's curl option CURLOPT_PASSWDFUNCTION, get notice:

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_PASSWDFUNCTION - assumed 'CURLOPT_PASSWDFUNCTION'
```

Sample:

```
function get_passwd($ch, $string, $length){
    return 'password';
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PASSWDFUNCTION, 'get_passwd');
```

PHP info:

PHP 5.4.40 (cli) (built: Apr 29 2015 02:17:51) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

What i do wrong?

UPD:
curl is working, when i execute my code i get message "please enter password", i enter password and get data over ssl using ecnryption and certificate. I want just avoid manual entering password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that this functionality has been removed:

> CURLOPT_PASSWDFUNCTION
>   Introduced in 7.4.2
>   Deprecated since 7.11.1
>   Last used in 7.11.1

latest curl release is 7.42.1

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking at the error I am assuming you haven't installed cURL libraries. If you have installed the cURL module make sure you have enabled it in your php.ini file. `echo phpinfo();` can help you to find if you have installed the cURL module correctly. You can just do `var_dump(CURLOPT_PASSWDFUNCTION);` to find out what value it has, if php is able to find it.

Comment: I am not sure what you are exactly trying achieve. There might be some other easier way to achieve what you are after. Did you try to var_dump(CURLOPT_PASSWDFUNCTION);

Comment: I think LevB would be right. This can be easily found out using var_dump that option which I would assume would show as null. If PHP displays var_dump value for other options and not for this particular one, it would prove it that this functionality does not exist